# I have patent applications for the same invention in different countries. Can I choose which application to use as priority for a PCT one?

Tags: provisional, pct, priority, us, australian

I have a US non-provisional that claims priority to a provisional one. It is not published yet but its priority period has expired. I also have a pending Australian provisional application for exactly the same invention. Can I file a PCT application claiming the priority date only of the Australian provisional which is the first application in this country but has a later filing date than the US one?

Comment: Does the australian one claim any priority?

Comment: No, it is a provisional one and it is independent, without claiming priority to the US one.

Comment: Is any of those published? Can you give us the dates?

Comment: None of them have been published yet. The invention is not published either. The dates are: US Provisional (02 April 2017); US Non-provisional, claiming priority to it (01 April 2018); Australian Provisional, without claiming any priority (29 April 2018)

Answer (score 1):

No. Under the Paris Convention you can only claim priority to the first filed application. The exception to this is if the first application is abandoned without being published and was never used in a priority claim, then the second application **in that same country** can be used for priority. Article 4 is very clear.

> Article 4 C (4) A subsequent application concerning the same subject
>   as a previous first application within the meaning of paragraph (2),
>   above, filed in the same country of the Union. shall be considered as
>   the first application, of which the filing date shall be the starting
>   point of the period of priority, if, at the time of filing the
>   subsequent application, the said previous application has been
>   withdrawn, abandoned, or refused, without having been laid open to
>   public inspection and without leaving any rights outstanding, and if
>   it has not yet served as a basis for claiming a right of priority. The
>   previous application may not thereafter serve as a basis for claiming
>   a right of priority.

Answer (score -1):

If I may summarize the timeline:
*02 April 2017 - US Provisional(Not published)

01 April 2018 - US Non-Provisional, converted from US Provisional (Not published) 

29 April 2018 - Australian Provisional (Not published)*

24 May 2018 - Day you asked the question

Can you file a PCT claiming the priority date of the Australian Provisional?  
**If you have not made any public disclosure, the answer is yes.**

The applicable rule here:

> Article 4.C(4) of the Paris Convention
>   dictates that the 12-month window for filing a PCT application
>   commences on the filing date of the earliest application in the
>   family.

In other words, you cannot file a PCT application based on the priority of your US Provisional because the 12-month window has passed.

However, you can still file a PCT application based on the priority of your Australian Provisional since you are still within the 12-month window.

Note that you will need to withdraw your US Non-Provisional to prevent the novelty of your subject matter in your PCT Application from being negated by the US Non-Provisional when it publishes.

This link provides more information: https://www.smithhopen.com/PCT_filing_deadlines_and_priority_dates.aspx

Comment: I can't find a PCT reference, but I think the PCT is in line with the epc on this (https://www.epo.org/law-practice/legal-texts/html/guidelines/e/f_vi_1_4_1.htm). The australian prov. was not the first application. It is not considered the first app. because the US non prov. and the us prov. had rights outstanding/were used for priority. Therefore the australian prov. would **not** be a valid priority application. Am I missing something or is the PCT rule different?

Comment: Good Point. But since the AUS Provisional does not claim priority to the earlier US Applications, once the US Non-Provisional is withdrawn, the PCT can claim priority to the AUS Provisional if the subject matter has not been publicly disclosed during the time between the US Provisional Application and the AUS Provisional.

Comment: but “the same invention“ relates to the subject matter independently of claiming priority. Example for ep: ep1 later ep2 later ep1 abandoned later ep3 claiming priority of ep2 all with identical content => priority not valid.

Comment: I'm not sure what happens if the applications are from different countries. But the us prov. has been used for claiming priority and should impede claiming priority even if the non. Prov is abandoned

Comment: Why do I need to abandon the US non-provisional, it is not in the same country? As far as I know Article 4.C(4) refers to subsequent applications in the same country. As far as I know I can file, in parallel, as many independent applications with different priority dates as I want in different countries that have signed the Paris Convention.

Comment: My Idea is to continue with the US non-provisional in the US and in parallel to file a PCT for the rest of the world  which I do not plan to enforce in US later. Which means that I want to secure the invention in US with the earlier priority date and to use the later, not so secure, priority date for the rest of the world. What is the problem with that if the priority date of the PCT (Based on the AUS one) is before the publication of the US non-provisional one? Why do you think they are going to consider the US application a prior art in this case if I do not abandon it?

Comment: @Piterz not prior art, but the epo requires you to claim priority from the youngest application for the same subject matter that still has rights outstanding. In my opinion the epo would therefore not recognize the priority of the pct from the aus because the us has the same subject matter (same invention).

Comment: @DonQuiKong, thank you for your expert opinion. You are probably right! I am confused because the quote of Smith & Hopen is “the earliest application in the family” but in Article 4.C.(2) the phrase is “first application” without defining if it means the first application worldwide or the first application in the country from which the application claims priority. “Patent family” is not mentioned at all and as far as I know it is not an unambiguous term and every patent office and database has different definition.

Comment: Moreover, Article 4.C.(4), which Smith & Hopen cite, actually defines what first application within a country means. They also pretend that a PCT application without claiming any priority will be invalid even if it is filed before the publication of the independent non-provisional patent application with the earlier priority date. Why? As far as I know, before publication of an application you can file independently as many applications in other countries and this application will not be considered prior art or “disclosure” and is not needed to be abandoned or withdrawn. Is that right?

Comment: It is also not clear in their example if it is just their interpretation of Article 4 or if it is based on an official interpretation from an institution, like WIPO for example, or on a specific real case.

Comment: @Piterz maybe they define as family all applications relating, whether they draw priority or not. Imho you can file independently as many applications as you want, but maybe there is a PCT provision impeding this.

Comment: @DonQuiKong I also thought so but Article 8 of the PCT which deals with priority claims redirects to Article 4 of the Paris Convension. Moreover in the regulations from this year it is written:
“2.4 Priority Period” (a )Whenever  the  term  “priority  period”  is  used  in  relation  to  a  priority claim, it shall be construed as meaning the period of 12 months from the filing date of the earlier application whose priority is so claimed.  The day of filing of the earlier application shall not be included in that period.”  They have even written "ealier", not "ealiest"!